# A shortcut to present all windows and jump to one of them with a key

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde

Is there a feature that present the "present all windows" screen or something similar and puts letters on the windows like 'alt' does for menu so you can jump to the desired window with just the keyboard ?

Comment: Why don't you use predefined `<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>` +<kbd>TAB</kbd> combination?

Comment: @Mahdia Thanks for the comment. Can you clarify? Where to define and how?

Comment: related:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387542/7832 -- tl;dr: one can use `ctrl + f9`, or set a screen edge (e.g., top right corner) so that e.g., `alt` + mouse in top-right-corner shows all windows at once, then select the one you want (I'm not sure if this is just kde, or also gnome, though; works for me in kubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is! You are looking for Window Spread.

Just press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and you will be presented with all the application windows currently running on that workspace. You can then use the arrow keys, or the mouse to choose a window.

**Note:** you can also have the same thing if you push your mouse pointer to the top-left corner of your display.

Comment: Thanks. <Alt> + W does not work out of the box in kubuntu 15.10. I found in "desktop effects" -> "present windows" -> "options" where to define the shortcut keys to activate that presentation.

Answer (score 1):

### Tutorial

1. Launch Custom Shortcuts by one of these ways:

   - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and search for "Desktop Effects".
   - Open the start menu (<kbd>Super</kbd>) and search for "Desktop Effects".
   - Open the start menu (<kbd>Super</kbd>) and launch *Settings > System Settings*  then go to *Workspace > Desktop Behaviour > Desktop Effects*.
2. Search for "Present Windows" then click the second icon/button to open options for it.
   [image: Desktop Effects in System Settings]
3. Go to the "Activation" panel and select the action *KWin > Toggle Present Windows (All desktops)* where you can see the current shortcuts. [image: Options for Present Windows]
4. Set a new shortcut by clicking the appropriate cell ("Global" vs "Global Alternate") then the button next to "Custom".

   - To overwrite the global shortcut click the cell in the 2nd column.
   - To add an alternate shortcut next to the global one click the cell in the 3rd column.

### Attribution

This is a more detailed and illustrated guide based on the solution from [@elpddev's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752216/a-shortcut-to-present-all-windows-and-jump-to-one-of-them-with-a-key#comment1122022_752216).